# function appears to be returning multiple results or: what is implicit tuple unpacking

Tags: python, for-loop

Can someone please explain the following line of code? Is it some kind of nested for loop? If so can someone rewrite it as an equivalent nested for loop. allPositions parameter is a list and synapsesPerSegment is an int variable.

```
for rx,ry in random.sample(allPositions, synapsesPerSegment):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a normal loop. No nesting. `random.sample` returns a list of elements from `allPositions`, taking `synapsesPerSegment` many items. As the variables being assigned to in the for loop are a tuple in the form `(rx, ry)`, this suggests that `allPositions` is a list (or collection) of tuples in the form `(rx, ry)`, which are assigned to `rx` and `ry` each iteration. If you have a list of tuples, the for loop 'unpacks' them each iteration to those variables. For example if you have

`(a, b) = (99, 100)`

then this assigment will unpack:

`(c, d) = (a, b)`

so that `c == 99` and `d == 100`.

To get back to the question, here is an walk through with some example data:

if we say:
`allPositions = [(1,100), (2, 200), (3, 300), (4, 400)]`

and, for example:
`synapsesPerSegment = 3`

then 
`random.sample(allPositions, synapsesPerSegment)` might produce `[(3, 300), (1,100), (2, 200)]` because it takes 3 items from `allPositions` at random.

then iterating over that:

- Iteration 1: `rx = 4`, `ry = 400`
- Iteration 2: `rx = 1`, `ry = 100`
- Iteration 3: `rx = 2`, `ry = 200`

Comment: Note that the fact that `allPositions` is a list of 2-tuples may not be 'obvious' to someone who hasn't seen the unpacking syntax before.

Comment: The way that `rx` and `ry` are assigned is an example of [tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a nested loop, it's called tuple unpacking. It may help you to think of it as roughly equivalent to doing this

```
for item in random.sample(allPositions, synapsesPerSegment):
    rx = item[0]
    ry = item[1]
```